# Adobe stratus VS Asterisk

Tags: adobe, voip, asterisk, skype, soundcloud-stratus

What is the best way to create a simple application that make PC-to-PC call ?

Why Stratus is better ?

Why Asterisk is better ?

Remember that stratus use a peer-to-peer protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always pick a solution that uses industry standards - in your case Asterisk.